# Update plot in for loop in function

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to call a function like in the example below, and plot while running the code. The real values that I get as y-data are not really random numbers, but the point is that I would like it to get updated real-time. The plot in my example code below is just empty though and isn't getting updated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as rnd
import time

initial_time = time.time()

def multiple_runs(number_of_runs):
    x_data, y_data = [], []
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sc = ax.scatter(x_data, y_data)
    plt.draw()

    for i in range(0, number_of_runs):
        x_data.append(i+1)
        y_data.append(rnd.randint(0,100))
        sc.set_offsets(np.c_[x_data, y_data])
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        plt.pause(0.1)

        print ('Total time after run number ' + str(i+1) + ': ' + str(time.time() - initial_time))

multiple_runs(100)
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest , I got the code to work. However my problem right now is that the figure closes down as soon as it's finished, is there anyway to keep it open? I tried using `plt.waitforbuttonpress()` but I get a strange error from `QTimer`, not sure how or why. This is my working example code;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as rnd
import time

initial_time = time.time()

def multiple_runs(number_of_runs):
    x_data, y_data = [], []
    x_data2, y_data2 = [], []
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex = True)
    sc = ax[0].scatter(x_data, y_data)
    sc2 = ax[1].scatter(x_data2, y_data2)
    ax[0].set(xlim=(0,100), ylim=(0,100))
    ax[1].set(xlim=(0,100), ylim=(0,100))
    plt.draw()

    for i in range(0, number_of_runs):
        x_data.append(i+1)
        y_data.append(rnd.randint(0,100))
        x_data2.append(i+1)
        y_data2.append(rnd.randint(0,100))
        sc.set_offsets(np.c_[x_data, y_data])
        sc2.set_offsets(np.c_[x_data2, y_data2])
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        plt.pause(0.1)

        print ('Total time after run number ' + str(i+1) + ': ' + str(time.time() - initial_time))

multiple_runs(100)
```

**UPDATE2:**
I tried using `FuncAnimation`, but getting the error `TypeError: update() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'y2'`. I still need to use the `for-loop` because in my real code I'm using the previous values of y, to calculate the next values of y. This is my example code which is giving me the error;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random as rnd
import time

initial_time = time.time()

def multiple_runs(number_of_runs):
    x_data, y_data = [], []
    x_data2, y_data2 = [], []
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex = True)
    sc = ax[0].scatter(x_data, y_data)
    sc2 = ax[1].scatter(x_data2, y_data2)
    ax[0].set(xlim=(0,100), ylim=(0,100))
    ax[1].set(xlim=(0,100), ylim=(0,100))

    def update(i, y, y2):
        x_data.append(i+1)
        y_data.append(y)
        x_data2.append(i+1)
        y_data2.append(y2)
        sc.set_offsets(np.c_[x_data, y_data])
        sc2.set_offsets(np.c_[x_data2, y_data2])
        print ('Total time after run number ' + str(i+1) + ': ' + str(time.time() - initial_time))


    for i in range(0, number_of_runs):
        y = rnd.randint(0,100)
        y2 = rnd.randint(0,100)
        update(i,y,y2)

    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=number_of_runs, interval=100, repeat=False)
    plt.show()

multiple_runs(100)
```

Comment: I suspect that you forgot to update the limits, i.e. all the points are much larger than 1, yet the axes limits go from 0 to 1, hence the points are shown outside of the visible range. Something like `ax.set(xlim=(0,100), ylim=(0,100))` will sure show them.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. If you put it as answer I will accept it with the green thing. If you have any solution for this, I just noticed that I can't use `plt.waitforbuttonpress()` to make the plot stay open after code is run, I get a strange error saying `QTimer::singleShot: Timers cannot have negative timeouts python error`. If you have any solution for this I would be very greatful, but not needed since the real problem is dealt with, I'll go with what I've got for now :)

Comment: I never used `waitforbuttonpress`. What is the purpose of this? Is it to show an animation? Did you consider using `FuncAnimation`?

Comment: I tried using `FuncAnimation`, but couldn't get it to work. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, I would recommend to use `FuncAnimation`. This would look as follows in your case. Note that in order to close the window, one would need to press <kbd>q</kbd> or close it with the mouse.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random as rnd
import time

initial_time = time.time()

def multiple_runs(number_of_runs):
    x_data, y_data = [], []
    x_data2, y_data2 = [], []
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex = True)
    sc = ax[0].scatter(x_data, y_data)
    sc2 = ax[1].scatter(x_data2, y_data2)
    ax[0].set(xlim=(0,100), ylim=(0,100))
    ax[1].set(xlim=(0,100), ylim=(0,100))

    def get_ydata(i):
        y = rnd.randint(0,100)
        y2 = rnd.randint(0,100)
        return y, y2

    def update(i):
        y, y2 = get_ydata(i)
        x_data.append(i+1)
        y_data.append(y)
        x_data2.append(i+1)
        y_data2.append(y2)
        sc.set_offsets(np.c_[x_data, y_data])
        sc2.set_offsets(np.c_[x_data2, y_data2])

    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=number_of_runs, interval=100, repeat=False)
    plt.show()

multiple_runs(100)
```

Comment: Huge thanks for helping out, but this didn't work in my case. See update2 in my question.

Comment: I updated the code. You shouldn't try to use any loop, because `FuncAnimation` **is** the loop.